# Vaadin 7 build with Maven, how to prevent style.css from being always re-generated

Tags: css, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I use vaadin 7 and I build it with maven.

There is a CSS file called 'the_name_of_myProject'/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css
If I modify it in any way, my modifications are overridden by the next maven build. Looks like the file is always re-generated from jars.

What can I do if I want those modifications to survive?

I have created my own theme with a different name but it did not help either because its .css were overridden in the same way.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you put your styles.css file? Maybe it needs a custom directory: `'the_name_of_myProject'/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/'my_theme_name'/styles.css`

Comment: yes, that was a typo, that I have already edited. Inside 'themes' folder there is another folder called 'mytheme' and the styles.css is there along with other .scss files. I wrote none of them, all were generated (and re-generated). So the problem is still there

Comment: So are you generating css from sass with maven? What if you put your custom css code into styles.scss?

Comment: yes that's the solution. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sass is an extension of CSS. Here is a description: [link](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.sass.html)
Maven generates CSS from Sass. You can put your custom css code into styles.scss.

Answer (score 2):

I used [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) at my pom.xml for generate css styles while maven build. At my *style.scss* file , I put all my custom scss files

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler</mainClass>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.scss</argument>
                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.css</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```